# How to scroll to the last element of iron-list (dart polymer 1.0)?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to scroll to the last element of `iron-list` after each update of its model but calling `IronList.scrollToIndex()` shows only part of the list. More clearly, I have polymer element:

```
@PolymerRegister('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
    @property
    List<String> items = [];

    MainApp.created() : super.created();

    @reflectable
    void onAdd([_, __]){
        var fst = items.length;
        var lst = new List.generate(30, (x) => (fst+x).toString());
        addAll("items", lst);
        ($['list'] as IronList).scrollToIndex(items.length-1);
   }
}
```

html:

```
<dom-module id="main-app">
    <template>
        <style>
            #list {
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <iron-list items="{{items}}" id="list">
            <template>
                <div>{{item}}</div>
            </template>
        </iron-list>
        <paper-button raised on-tap="onAdd">add</paper-button>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

When I click on the button for the first time it gives me:

[image]

What's wrong here? How to update the view properly?
(package versions: `polymer 1.0.0-rc.6`, `polymer_elements 1.0.0-rc.3`, `polymer_interop 1.0.0-rc.5`)

Comment: Can you try to wrap the line with `scrollToIndex` with `async(() => ...)`?

Comment: Wrapping it with `async` gives me no visible effect.

Comment: looks like an async problem or an issue with scrollToIndex. Have you check the Polymer issues?

Comment: This looks quite close https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/issues/21. There is also a comment of someone running into this issue after it was closed as fixed. I can reproduce as well in Dartium and Chrome (resizing the browser reveals the missing items). Best way to get this fixed in Polymer (if this actually is this bug) is to create a repo as Plunker, JsFiddle, ... and create a bug report in the iron-list GitHub repo.

Comment: Ok, I've added bug report: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/issues/140